# How to configure the ssh plug in for Visual Studio Code in case the remote server uses port knocking?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, debian, visual-studio-code

So there is a server which has port knocking (e.g by using linux subsystem for windows)  I can easily ssh to by

$ knock -v "ip of the server" Xport:udp Yport:udp Zport:udp

$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/test2 "username@"ip of the server" -p "custom port set for ssh"

but I would like to use Visual Studio Code https://code.visualstudio.com/download

It has an ssh-plug in but trying to connect to the server always returns an error.

this is how I have set the configuration file

```
Host <ip of the server>:<customport>
HostName <ip of the server>:<customport>
User <username>
IdentityFile   C:\Users\Admin\.ssh\test2
```

`test2` is my private key (which I also use just fine when trying to connect with the linux console) and I copied that to the directory visible in the config file.

I am not sure that the root of the issue is due to port knocking since I tried manually (using my linux subsystem for windows console from the same machine and network) to knock the ports before trying to connect with visual studio code but it doesnt work

I also tried to add this line to the configuration file

`BatchMode wls knock -v "ip of the server" Xport:udp Yport:udp Zport:udp`

In hopes that  MVScode will knock the ports that way (wls is an executable that allows you to run linux console commands on CMD if I open CMD for example and run wls ls it will list the files on the linux subsystem within the cmd window, also tried to knock the ports that way and worked as well)

But I still am getting errors.

Any solution you could think of? Thanks.

P.S In case it is not apparent by now the taget server runs linux (Debian to be exact)
Also the system that I run VisualStudioCode runs Windows 10.